# How to access the EE control panel

Tags: control-panel

I know this is a lame question but I have not updated any content for 6 years.  My site is hosted by EngineHosting and I can FTP to the files. How do you access the ExpressionEngine control panel.  The URL I use to use no longer works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could acces using :

www.mysite.com/admin.php

Add /admin.php after your domain site name to access to the EE Control Panel.

Comment: Assuming the `admin.php` file is present and has not been renamed, or it isn't a really old version of EE. Since you can connect to the server look around for either the admin.php file (or similar, if renamed). Or search for a `system` directory in the web root (or similar, if renamed).